# Xml simplification/extraction of distinct values - possible LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

Sorry for this long post....But i have a headache from this task.

I have a mile long xml document where I need to extract a list, use distinct values, and pass for transformation to web.

I have completed the task using xslt and keys, but the effort is forcing the server to its knees.

Description:
hundreds of products in xml, all with a number of named and Id'ed cattegories, all categories with at least one subcategory with name and id.

The categories are unique with ID, all subcategories are unique WITHIN that category:

Simplified example form the huge file (left our tons of info irrelevant to the task):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<productlist>
<product id="1">
<name>Some Product</name>
<categorylist>
<category id="1">
<name>cat1</name>
<subcategories>
<subcat id="1">
<name>subcat1</name>
</subcat>
<subcat id="2">
<name>subcat1</name>
</subcat>
</subcategories>
</category>
<category id="2">
<name>cat1</name>
<subcategories>
<subcat id="1">
<name>subcat1</name>
</subcat>
</subcategories>
</category>
<category id="3">
<name>cat1</name>
<subcategories>
<subcat id="1">
<name>subcat1</name>
</subcat>
</subcategories>
</category>
</categorylist>
</product>
<product id="2">
<name>Some Product</name>
<categorylist>
<category id="1">
<name>cat1</name>
<subcategories>
<subcat id="2">
<name>subcat2</name>
</subcat>
<subcat id="4">
<name>subcat4</name>
</subcat>
</subcategories>
</category>
<category id="2">
<name>cat2</name>
<subcategories>
<subcat id="1">
<name>subcat1</name>
</subcat>
</subcategories>
</category>
<category id="3">
<name>cat3</name>
<subcategories>
<subcat id="1">
<name>subcat1</name>
</subcat>
</subcategories>
</category>
</categorylist>
</product>
</productlist>
</root>
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<maincat id="1">
<name>cat1</name>
<subcat id="1"><name>subcat1</name></subcat>
<subcat id="2"><name>subcat2</name></subcat>
<subcat id="3"><name>subcat3</name></subcat>
</maincat>
<maincat id="2">
<name>cat2</name>
<subcat id="1"><name>differentsubcat1</name></subcat>
<subcat id="2"><name>differentsubcat2</name></subcat>
<subcat id="3"><name>differentsubcat3</name></subcat>
</maincat>
<maincat id="2">
<name>cat2</name>
<subcat id="1"><name>differentsubcat1</name></subcat>
<subcat id="2"><name>differentsubcat2</name></subcat>
<subcat id="3"><name>differentsubcat3</name></subcat>
</maincat>
</root>
```

(original will from 2000 products produce 10 categories with from 5 to 15 subcategories)

Things tried:

1. Xslt with keys - works fine, but pooooor performance
2. Played around with linq:

   ```
          IEnumerable<XElement> mainCats =
                   from Category1 in doc.Descendants("product").Descendants("category") select Category1;

               var cDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null), new XElement("root"));
               cDoc.Root.Add(mainCats);
               cachedCategoryDoc = cDoc.ToString();
   ```

   Result was a "categories only" (not distinct values of categories or subcategories)

Applied the same xlst to that, and got fairly better performance..... but still far from usable...

Can i apply some sort of magic with the linq statement to have the desired output??

A truckload of good karma goes out to the ones that can point me in det right direction..

//Steen

NOTE:

- I am not stuck on using linq/XDocument if anyone has better options
- Currently on .net 3.5, can switch to 4 if needed

Comment: Thanks for the competent replies! I did not get time to try things out before a vacation last week....

Comment: It turned out, that our development server was handling 50+ sites, so that partly affected the processing of the xslt based solution already implemented. The provider of the data has given me the option to do the processing AND caching on their server......so that solves all problems, and transfers the performance load away from webserver...

BUT, many thanks for the replies, upvotes to all - I will probably get a chance to try out some of it on other projects :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question corectly, here's a LINQ atempt.

The query below parses your XML data and creates a custom type which represents a category and contains the subcategories of that element.

After parsing, the data is grouped by category Id to get distinct subcategories for each category.

```
var doc = XElement.Load("path to the file");
var results = doc.Descendants("category")
    .Select(cat => new
    {
        Id = cat.Attribute("id").Value,
        Name = cat.Descendants("name").First().Value,
        Subcategories = cat.Descendants("subcat")
            .Select(subcat => new
            {
                Id = subcat.Attribute("id").Value,
                Name = subcat.Descendants("name").First().Value
            })
     })
     .GroupBy(x=>x.Id)
     .Select(g=>new
     {
         Id = g.Key,
         Name = g.First().Name,
         Subcategories = g.SelectMany(x=>x.Subcategories).Distinct()
     });
```

From the results above you can create your document using the code below:

```
var cdoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null), new XElement("root")); 
cdoc.Root.Add(
    results.Select(x=>
    {
        var element = new XElement("maincat", new XAttribute("id", x.Id));
        element.Add(new XElement("name", x.Name));
        element.Add(x.Subcategories.Select(c=>
        {
            var subcat = new XElement("subcat", new XAttribute("id", c.Id));
            subcat.Add(new XElement("name", c.Name));
            return subcat;
        }).ToArray());
        return element;
    }));
```

Comment: Hi RePierre, please see comments on question.

I was working along the same path, but generally messed it up.... think I can see more or less where..

Comment: RePierre, I have chosen your answer as the best answer, without trying it out (as time spent on an already solved issue can't be billed the customer), but it seems that it would indeed be a complete solution with ids and all.....and as I wrote before, its pretty close to how I imagined it my self before I got lost in the wood..

Answer (score 1):

Try this i have done something for it.. attributes are missing you can add them using XElement ctor

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                    IEnumerable<XElement> mainCats =
                        doc.Descendants("product").Descendants("category").Select(r =>
                            new XElement("maincat", new XElement("name", r.Element("name").Value),
                                r.Descendants("subcat").Select(s => new XElement("subcat", new XElement("name", s.Element("name").Value)))));


                    var cDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null), new XElement("root"));
                    cDoc.Root.Add(mainCats);
                    var cachedCategoryDoc = cDoc.ToString();
```

Regards.

Comment: Shoaib,  please see comments on question. The answer looks short and neat though (as in effective :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will parse your xml into a dictionary of categories with all the distinct subcategory names.  It uses XPath from this library: https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
string[] cats = root.XGet("//category/name", string.Empty).Distinct().ToArray();
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
foreach (string cat in cats)
{
    // Get all the categories by name and their subcat names
    string[] subs = root
        .XGet("//category[name={0}]/subcategories/subcat/name", string.Empty, cat)
        .Distinct().ToArray();
    dict.Add(cat, subs);
}
```

Or the parsing as one statement:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = root
    .XGet("//category/name", string.Empty)
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(cat => cat, cat => root
        .XGet("//category[name={0}]/subcategories/subcat/name", string.Empty, cat)
        .Distinct().ToArray());
```

I give you the task of assembling your resulting xml from the dictionary.

Comment: Hi Chuck, please see comments on question. The libary looks very interesting. The ability to use xpaths more like in the xslts could have helped me on several occasions.